# Why does mysql_secure_installation never work?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed mysql server on 3 different servers (all Ubunutu 18.04). According to almost all the installation tutorials, after installation I am suppose to run `sudo mysql_secure_installation` where, among other things, the root password is set. However, after this utility runs, I am still not able to access mysql using the following:

```
mysql -u root -p

>ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

What I have to do is `sudo` into mysql and alter the root password using the following:

```
sudo mysql
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'pass123';
```

**Why can I not log in as root after setting the password with `mysql_secure_installation`?** I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: Same problem on 20.04 - this really never seems to work. After doing mysql_secure_installation with setting a root password now i still can login to mysql without password and when i try to login with root credentials (from php script) it tells me those are the wrong credentials.